# How do you implement a Dictionary in XAML in XAMARIN?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Being an advocate of MVVM design, I only work with enums in my view models for graphics objects.  I defer the association to an actual bitmap until the view needs a bitmap.  In WPF and UWP, I used a dictionary that looked like this:

```
<trcontrols:UriCategory>
    <trcontrols:UriSource x:Key="Alert"
                          Uri="ms-appx:///ThetaRex.InvestmentManager.Views/Assets/Banner/Alert.png"/>
    <trcontrols:UriSource x:Key="Application"
                          Uri="ms-appx:///ThetaRex.InvestmentManager.Views/Assets/Banner/Application.png"/>
    <trcontrols:UriSource x:Key="Folder"
                          Uri="ms-appx:///ThetaRex.InvestmentManager.Views/Assets/Banner/Folder.png"/>
    <trcontrols:UriSource x:Key="Blotter"
                          Uri="ms-appx:///ThetaRex.InvestmentManager.Views/Assets/Banner/Blotter.png"/>
    <trcontrols:UriSource x:Key="Portfolio"
                          Uri="ms-appx:///ThetaRex.InvestmentManager.Views/Assets/Banner/Portfolio.png"/>
</trcontrols:UriCategory>
```

This code doesn't port to XAMARIN.  This is what works in WPF and UWP:

```
[ContentProperty("Content")]
public class UriCategory
{
    public UriCategory()
    {
        this.Content = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public IDictionary Content { get; }
}
```

But in XAMARIN, I get 'Sequence contains no matching element'.  It looks like it's trying some LINQ 'First' operation, but I can't extract anything useful out of the call stack.

Does anyone have an implementation of a Dictionary in XAML in XAMARIN that they can share?

Comment: It would be easier if you could tell me what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: **Does anyone have an implementation of a Dictionary in XAML in XAMARIN that they can share?**

Comment: Implementation of dictionary to do what? Your question is still vague

Comment: To look up a concrete resource based on an integer or enum or string used by the View Model.  The View Model shouldn't have any knowledge of the implementation, so the dictionary serves as a way of translating an abstract value (e.g. AlertIcon = 5), into a real resource (e.g. "ms-appx:///MyCompany.MyProject.Views/Assets/Banner/Alert.png").

Comment: There are ResourceDictionaries, which are definitely accessible via code-behind, so I'm not sure if you've fully investigated that. It's hard to say if they can do exactly what you want without seeing more of your code.

Comment: I think I would tend to use a binding Converter for the purposes you're describing. If you just need to translate the name of an image to the image itself, you could bind to a string "Alert", and XF should jsut find the Alert.png automatically if it's in the normal place.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the code-behind.  I have an Image control.  That image control is bound to a view model.  The view model only knows strings, integers and enums, it doesn't know Images or Uris.  How do I translate between the (let's use a) string in my View Model and an Image resource?

Comment: Just bind the string to the Source of the image will work. See [document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=macos#downloading-images).

Comment: Also, a [Binding Value Converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters) can be used to help you transfer data.